# MVVM Light throws (Did you forget to call > NavigationService.Configure? Parameter name: pageKey) exception

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I am making a Universal winrt app using mvvm light. In ViewModelLocator I've registered my view in the builtin NavigationService of mvvm light

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() =>
{
    var navigationService = new NavigationService();
    navigationService.Configure("PreRegisterPage", typeof(PreRegisterPage));
    return navigationService;
});
```

But when I try to navigate to that page using this code,

```
 _navigationService.NavigateTo("PreRegisterPage");
```

It throws this exception

> No such page: PreRegisterPage. Did you forget to call
>   NavigationService.Configure? Parameter name: pageKey

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is some context missing.

Comment: Check the inner exception.  It might be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: The inner exception is null

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to pass an `INavigationService` object in the `ViewModel` ctor, here how your `ViewModel` should looks like:

```
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    private RelayCommand _navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _navigateCommand
                ?? (_navigateCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                    _navigationService.NavigateTo("PreRegisterPage");
                }));
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;           
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine at my end !
here how i usually register the NavigationService https://github.com/SamTheDev/ToxRt/blob/master/ToxRt/ToxRt.Shared/ViewModel/ViewModelLocator.cs#L31

Comment: and here how i pass it https://github.com/SamTheDev/ToxRt/blob/master/ToxRt/ToxRt.Shared/Helpers/NavigableViewModelBase.cs#L20

Comment: you are probably missing something, show us more of your code please

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the `PageService` object, you have to call the `Configure` method with the `ViewModel` and the `Page` classes. As in the following:

```
Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
```

The code for displaying the error message above is also in `PageService.cs`.  I think it's a stupid way of doing it.